# What is `conn, addr = s.accept()` in python socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, python-sockets

I searched documentations and tutorials but no one talked about this, for example this is server script

```
import socket
 
server = socket.socket()
print("socket created")

server.bind(("localhost", 9999))
server.listen(3)
print("waiting for connection")

while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print(client)
    print(addr)
    
    name = client.recv(1024).decode()
    print("connected with", addr, client, name)
    
    client.send(b"welcome bro")       
    client.close()
```

When printing `client`, I get this:

```
proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 9999), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 36182)
```

And `addr` variable :

```
('127.0.0.1', 36182)
```

Why these two variable defined by one and got two different output?

What is the logic behind scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of the socked module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects):

**socket.accept()**

> Accept a connection. The socket must be bound to an
> address and listening for connections. The return value is a pair
> (conn, address) where conn is a new socket object usable to send and
> receive data on the connection, and address is the address bound to
> the socket on the other end of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The script does not answer this by itself, however, I assume laddr=('127.0.0.1', 9999) is the listening address of the server-side app. That's where connections are established. the raddr is the connection port the request comes from. When you listen to a port with a server, the client uses any non-reserved port >1024 to connect to the server and this is totally random, as long as it is defined in the client-app.

So you have to different connection points for one established connection. The one port and address as the sender-side (described as raddr) and the one as the receiver side (here described as laddr - for listen)

That's basically the logic behind any TCP-related connection.

Answer (score 0):

`accept()` function returns a socket descriptor that is connected to your TCP server. In this case, it returns a tuple  of objects.

The first parameter, `conn`, is a socket object that you can use to send data to  and receive data from the client that is connected.

The second parameter, `addr`, contains address information about the client that is connected(e.g., IP address and remote part).